# Tensor product of suspensions and its inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations, tensor-products

Let $A$ be a graded vector space. Define the suspension $S(A)^d=A^{d+1}$, where the superindex indicates the degree component, so that the map $S:A\to S(A)$ given by the identity in each degree has degree $-1$.

**Main question**

We can take the tensor product of suspensions as $S^{\otimes n}:A^{\otimes n}\to S(A)^{\otimes n}$ by applying $S$ to each component. I've been told that the inverse $(S^{\otimes n})^{-1}$ is not the same as $(S^{-1})^{\otimes n}$ but I don't see why. Since $(S^{-1})^{\otimes n}$ applies $S^{-1}$ to each component, it should reverse what is done by $S^{\otimes n}$.

**Application of this**

Let $f\in C^{n,i}(A,A)=\hom(A^{\otimes n},A)^i$, i.e. $f$ is a linear map of arity $n$ and degree $i$. Define $\sigma(f)\in C^{n,i+n-1}(S(A),S(A))$ by

$\sigma(f)=(-1)^{i+n-1}S\circ f\circ (S^{-1})^{\otimes n}$

I've been told that the inverse $\sigma^{-1}$ takes this form for $F\in C^{m,j}(S(A),S(A))$:

$\sigma^{-1}(F)=(-1)^{j+\binom{m}{2}}S^{-1}\circ F\circ S^{\otimes m}\in C^{m,j-m+1}$.

However, if I compute $\sigma^{-1}(\sigma(f))$ I get

$(-1)^{i+n-1+\binom{n}{2}}(-1)^{i+n-1}S^{-1}\circ S\circ f\circ (S^{-1})^{\otimes n}\circ S^{\otimes n}=(-1)^{\binom{n}{2}}f\circ (S^{-1})^{\otimes n}\circ S^{\otimes n}.$

Now, I am tempted to cancel the last two maps. But even if they are not inverses of each other, none of them have any signs in the definition, so I can't see why I would get that $(-1)^{\binom{n}{2}}$.

Comment: Usually for graded algebras we need that $A^dA^{d'}\subseteq A^{d+d'}$, so the suspension $S(A)$ is not a graded algebra in this sense.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro that's why I also said vector space, just in case there was some issue, since I mainly care about the linear structure. That problem can be sorted out by taking a new grading, but I don't really care about that. I'll edit the question. And actually I already solved it, but thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's missing is the application of the Koszul sign rule. Since $S$ has degree $-1$ and $S^{-1}$ has degree $1$, one has $S^{-1}\otimes S^{-1}(S\otimes S)=(-1)^{-1}S^{-1}S\otimes S^{-1}S=-Id$. In general,

$(S^{-1})^{\otimes n}\circ S^{\otimes n}=(-1)^{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i} (S^{-1}S)^{\otimes n}=(-1)^{\binom{n}{2}}Id$.

That also solves the problem with the inverse, since that precisely the sign needed.